# Adjusting time intervals for break periods?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2005

My program has a grid describing productivity statistics and goals, with columns for time intervals. This data is queried from a SQL Server 2005 database, summing the rows of data produced with timestamps for each row. Typically, the intervals of time are 1 hour in length:

```
               |6AM-7AM | 7AM-8AM | 8AM-9AM |
Units Produced |   25   |    27   |   24    |
     Unit Goal |   26   |    26   |   26    |
```

However, during the break periods where productivity is expected to be zero, the users want to include the break period in the preceding time interval, while maintaining the goal amount.

Example for a 30 minute meal break:

```
               |6AM-7AM | 7AM-8AM | 8AM-9AM | 9AM-10:30AM | 10:30AM-11:30AM |
Units Produced |   25   |    27   |   24    |     26      |       21        |
     Unit Goal |   26   |    26   |   26    |     26      |       26        |
```

Two 15 minute breaks would also be incorporated throughout the 8.5 hour long day (with 7.5 working hours).

My current implementation hard codes these hour range values on their own table, but this does not allow for easy variations in break times. "Handicapping" the goal value is not acceptable, per the users' requirements (This was my first design).

Should this be handled on the database layer, or on the application layer, and what is the best schema for implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up handling this in the database layer as a stored procedure, and a hard coded table.

I start by querying the start and end times for the day as a whole (ie 9AM-5PM). I then query from a hard coded table the specific hour intervals, one hour per row, as a start and end time for each segment. Next, I get a count of productivity between the timestamps, and format the two timestamps as a range label (a single column as a varchar, '8AM-9AM') to display on a graph.

It's not extremely elegant, but it works for my purposes.